# Does anyone know how/why this "every SIM card has a name" thing works?

Tags: facebook

I've seen pictures like this on Facebook:

[image]

The instructions claim that your SIM card has a unique name that can be displayed by inputting a command of the form

```
@[x:0]
```

where `x` is the last 3 digits of your phone number.

I don't believe for a second this has anything to do with your phone number/SIM card, but it does "work". When I posted the command into a text box  on Facebook it was replaced with a name.

I don't recognise the syntax with the `@`, but the square brackets makes me think it's some kind of array.

When I enter `@[123:0]` as a status update, the name `Morgan Grice` is the output. I wonder if the output name varies based on the user entering the command, or whether `@[123:0]` always outputs `Morgan Grice` (difficult for me to find out on my own).

Does anyone know how this is happening and explain how, for example, `@[123:0]` becomes `Morgan Grice`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you discovered is just a way of referencing to Facebook User by his `id` ([`123` is Morgan Grice](http://graph.facebook.com/123)).

You can just use any Facebook User `id` (and probably Facebook Page too, or even any OpenGraph object `id`) that way.

Comment: Does this mean the `@` is something specific to Facebook, or a more general construct in something like, say, JavaScript?

Comment: `@` just used by Facebook that way. That expanded to Names with links only on publishing.

Comment: What does the ':' and the number following that signify? Type of profile?

Comment: So then this has nothing to do with your mobile number or SIM card then?

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the process correctly you do actually see a name appearing. But the truth is that there is no relation between with your mobile number and Facebook.

The name is appearing is due to Facebook’s shorthand code. All Facebook users and pages are assigned with a unique ID number. When that ID number is typed into a comment box or status along with the symbols described in the message above, it displays the name of that corresponding Facebook user or page. For example, typing in @[666:0] reveals the name of Facebook user with the ID number 666. The ID number can be of more than 3 number, you can even use 4 numbers for above trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything within these constraints. 
Maximum: `@[1247229:#]` Minimum: `@[26:#]` 
(#= 0-infinity, or no number at all. Example: `@[123:]`, `@[123:0]`, `@123:9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999]` -- It works out to be the same) 
Within these constraints, what you put will be replaced by a name. 
Turns out that these constraints only apply to this small section of users. Feel free to experiment with this.